# How to solve such symmetric equations

Tags: symmetric-functions

I have the following symmetric system:

$$f_i = \sum_j^n \tau_{ij}c_j^{-1}y_j$$
$$c_j = \sum_i^n \tau_{ij}f_i^{-1}y_i$$
$$\tau_{ij}=\tau_{ji}$$

$$F = 
 \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   f_1  \\
   ... \\
   f_n 
  \end{matrix}
  \right] 
$$

$$C = 
 \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   c_1  \\
   ... \\
   c_n 
  \end{matrix}
  \right] 
$$

and how to solve the $f_i$ and $c_i$?

Does this two equations have the reduced form relationship?

Is there any theory that relate to such kind of symmetric system?

Thank you!

Comment: Can this system be readily transformed into a set of matrix equations? Also, what is the dimension of the system, Do both summation indices run to, say, $n$?

Comment: Yes, it can be transformed into a set of matrix equations.